# TKinter creating buttons and labels from functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, class, tkinter

I'm working on a small hobby project to build a dice rolling app, currently using tkinter. I've got this large block of code to create the buttons and labels needed for each die, but it looks a mess to repeat it for each type.

```
counter_d4 = Tk.IntVar()
counter_d4.set(0)
modify_d4 = Tk.IntVar()
modify_d4.set(0)
total_d4 = Tk.IntVar()
total_d4.set(0)

display_str_d4 = Tk.StringVar()
display_str_d4.set("")

b_plus_d4 = Tk.Button(root, text = "+", command = lambda: clicked_add(counter_d4))
b_plus_d4.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
b_minus_d4 = Tk.Button(root, text = "-", command = lambda: clicked_subtract(counter_d4))
b_minus_d4.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

b_plus_mod_d4 = Tk.Button(root, text = "+", command = lambda: clicked_add(modify_d4))
b_plus_mod_d4.grid(row = 0, column = 6)
b_minus_mod_d4 = Tk.Button(root, text = "-", command = lambda: clicked_subtract_mod(modify_d4))
b_minus_mod_d4.grid(row = 0, column = 4)

L_d4_name = Tk.Label(root, text = "D4")
L_d4_name.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
L_d4_count = Tk.Label(root, textvariable = counter_d4)
L_d4_count.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
L_d4_mod = Tk.Label(root, textvariable = modify_d4)
L_d4_mod.grid(row = 0, column = 5)
L_d4_total = Tk.Label(root, textvariable = display_str_d4)
L_d4_total.grid(row = 0, column = 7)
```

How would I go about turning this into a function or other condensed way? The main issue I'm running into is how to get the variable names to be built from some sort of list or function call.

I've been researching dictionaries, but not sure how to interact with them in terms of tkinter variables.  Or would creating classes be a better approach?

Comment: In my PC, it seems that a `RuntimeError` is raised.

Comment: Using class (inherited from tkinter `Frame`) is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

you simply want to "clone" the buttons, but with a slight diffrence to every one of them. this is a very common subject in programming, and there's a lot of diffrent ways to do this. i see that you're just learning dictionaries, so these two options are the best for this situation:

## option 1: using a function

if you want to simply automate the action of creating a button, and nothing else, then you could just a function that creates a button, here is an example:

```py
def create_button(text, command, rows, columns):
    button = Tk.Button(root, text=text, command=command)
    button.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
    return button
```

this is easier to both use and create, but is more complicated when the project grows larger, so i would suggest using it if you plan on making a small project.

## option 2: creating a "factory" class

a factory class is similar to what you're looking for, it's class for creating and handling a large amout of instances of the a class. here is an example:

```py
class Factory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buttons = []
    def create_button(self, text, command, rows, columns):
        new_button = Tk.Button(root, text=text, command=command)
        new_button.grid(row=rows, column=columns)

        self.buttons.append(new_button)
```

this takes much more time and effort to make, but if you have a ton of buttons you need to create, then it's way easier to use then a function. so use it if you plan on making a large project.